# GetObject is crashing UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am using UFT 11.53 with all the necessary patches installed. I have a function called MinimizeQTP which contains the following code.

```
Set objQTP = GetObject("","Quicktest.Application")
objQTP.Minimize
```

As soon as the control comes to the GetObject line QTP crashes.

Has anyone seen this problem before and could you advise what I am doing wrong?

**Note**: I have asked this question in [another form](http://knowledgeinbox.com/forums/uft-qtp-bpt-st/getobject-is-crashing-uft/).

Comment: It's strange, cause when I played test with  `Window("regexpwndtitle:=HP Unified Functional Testing.*").Minimize`  It didn't work, but when I am running from step that invokes this line it works...

Comment: I am using `Window("regexpwndtitle:=HP Unified Functional Testing.*").Minimize` as the workaround for the GetObject code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code for minimizing :

```
Function MinimizeQTPWindow

    Set oQTPApp = GetObject("","QuickTest.Application")
        oQTPApp.WindowState = "Minimized"

    Set oQTPApp = Nothing 

End Function
```

oQTPApp is an instance of QTP APP itself and It's not an instance of window like browser, that's why we can not use oQTPApp.minimize
Hope this help

Comment: Sorry that is a typo in my question. I'll correct my code. In the actual script i have the correct quotes.

Comment: Just try the code and let me know  , you gotta use  oQTPApp.WindowState = "Minimized" instead of oQTPApp.minimize   It's not an instance of window , it's an instance of QTP App . hope this helps